# SQL - правильность запрос с REGEXP

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT t1.dates_times, t1.file, t2.agent 
FROM ftp_json_stat t1, ftp_json t2 
WHERE t1.keys REGEXP '^(.{8})' = t2.keys
```

в t1.keys значения вида: d0790b5d_2018071323

в t2.keys значения вида: d0790b5d

При выполнении запроса - висит, потом отваливается по времени максимального выполнения. Записей в базах не много (100 000).

Запрос правильно составлен? Не могу понять почему висит, может быть получается очень большое количество записей которые он хочет выбрать из-за корявости запроса?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> в t1.keys значения вида: d0790b5d_2018071323
>
> в t2.keys значения вида: d0790b5d

Если нужно сравнить значение из t2 с первой до подчёркивания группой из t1, используйте, например

```
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.keys, '_', 1) = t2.keys
```

Если длина сравниваемой подстроки фиксирована (8 символов), можно использовать и прямое выделение нужного количества символов

```
WHERE LEFT(t1.keys, 8) = t2.keys
```

PS. REGEXP в MySQL в принципе ничего не преобразовывает - только проверяет.

Answer (score 0):

Пробуйте так:

```
SELECT t1.dates_times, t1.file, t2.agent FROM ftp_json_stat t1
JOIN ftp_json t2 ON t1.keys REGEXP CONCAT('^', t2.keys)
```

Comment: Попробовал. Висит также долго и отваливается. Странно что не так.

Comment: *Попробовал. Висит также долго и отваливается.* Проверить 100к литералов по 100к шаблонов? да тут любой сервер загнётся...